# How to write a data frame in a string in R

Tags: r

I need to write a text file that looks like this:

```
Header text
More Header text
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
More text
0 2
1 4
2 6
3 9
```

The numeric values are stored in two data frames.

So I thought about using write.table that does exactly what I need. I was thinking of something like this:

```
header <- "Header text \n More Header text"
df.text1 <- write.table(my.df1, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
more.text <- "More text"
df.text2 <- write.table(my.df2, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)

writeLines(paste(header, df.text1, more.text, df.text2, sep = "\n"), my.file)
```

The problem is, write.table writes to a file or connection, and I don't know how to write in a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `append = TRUE` in `write` and `write.table` to append to an existing file.

```
write(line, file="myfile", append=TRUE)
write.table(df, file="myfile", append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write to my.file directly:

```
cat(header,"\n",file= my.file)
write.table(my.df1, row.names = F, col.names = F,file= my.file,append=T)
cat(more.text,"\n",file= my.file,append=T)
write.table(my.df2, row.names = F, col.names = F,file= my.file,append=T)
```